# Handling initialization of fragment view models with MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

It appears that `MvxTabsFragmentActivity` does not call the `Init()` method on fragment view models as the tab is selected (nor at all). This was confirmed by taking a look at the source for [MvxTabsFragmentActivity](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/MvxTabsFragmentActivity.cs).

This is slightly annoying since it breaks the Init / Start model that view models are meant to implement (if they are to remain unaware that they are being used as tabs).

What is the recommended pattern around handling initialization (and other life-cycle stages for that matter) for view models that are used with tag fragments?

Answer (score 1):

The `MvxTabsFragmentActivity` works on pre-built view models - the ViewModel is passed to it using APIs like:

```
    protected void AddTab<TFragment>(string tagAndSpecName, string tabName, Bundle args,
                                     IMvxViewModel viewModel)
```

The responsibility of creating ViewModel's is the caller - if the caller uses `new` to create them, then `Init()` and `Start()` won't be called. If the caller uses `IMvxViewModelLoader.Load()` then `Init()` and `Start()` will be called.

Comment: That makes sense, and thanks for the pointer to `IMvxViewModelLoader`. How would you support scenarios where you want to delay loading the data (from the network, for example) until the user selects the tab?